# Can you know where is the request for API coming from in Laravel?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, rest, api

Basically, I have a RESTful API in laravel and I don't want to let anyone access the api so I created an APIKey middleware. Normally I would just check if the API key in the request URL equals the one assigned to the user. But since I plan to build and let others build php, js, etc. apps on the API I thought it was a good idea to check if the API Key equals the website or application the user registered when he requested an API key. How should I approach this problem?

Example middleware:

```
class APIKey
{ 

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    { 

       if ($request->apikey == '') {

            return redirect('/');

        } else { 

            $users = User::where('access_key', $request->apikey)->where('registered_app', $request->origin);

            if ($users != 1) { 
              return response("Invalid access key");
            } else { 
              return $next($request);
            }
        } 
   }
}
```

Pardon the syntax errors.

Comment: Check if [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport) helps

Comment: +1 for Laravel Passport. You probably shouldn't roll your own API auth, theres a lot of considerations that Passport handles.

Answer (score 0):

first you should write your query properly

```
 $user = User::where('access_key', $request->apikey)->where('registered_app', $request->origin)->first();
```

this should return a valid user, if not:

```
    if ($users != null) { 
      return response("Invalid access key");
    } else { 
      return $next($request);
    }
```

this should work.

Comment: `exist()` is better than `first()` if you want to check if record exists but do not want to select